# EntityFramwework Sort By address column excluding house number

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sorting, linq-to-entities

**Sorting address by the Alpha numeric not by house number**

How can i Sort a address field by the street name (**not number**), in other words either by splitting the address field by the number `var query = db.csutomer.OrderBy(e=> e.Address.Split(' ')[1]`.

**or by doing something like this** `var query = db.csutomer.OrderBy(e=> e.Address.Replace(NUMBER, ABC)`

neither of the approaches worked for me  `e.Address.Split(' ')[1]` is not a valid linq to  entity statement

also `e.Address.Replace(number, abc)` did not work

Comment: Here is an example `var query = queryBeforeExecution.OrderBy(e=> e.Address).ThenBy(e => e.City + e.State + e.Zip) ` i have tried to do e.AddressSplit(' ')[0] but this is not valid, is there anyway i can strip the numeric characters before executing the statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, you have NO idea what you are asking for.

"removing the house number" is something I spend half a year years ago. Things are not totally easy. What about "A 5 22"?

Your simple solution totally breaks apart for something simple like "Brandon Street 33 Apt 22".

It is not doable in SQL - this is why pretty much every databsae I ever have seen has the house and even appartement / unit number in separate fields. SQL just is not good for stuff that requires heavy text processing, and addresses are particularly nasty to parse to start with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Is it possible to strip all numbers before sending the query to the database, let's just say i don't need the order of the Unit number just the street name

Comment: Ah, strip all numbers. Yeah. "3d street" turns into what then? ;) How do A LOT of streets have numbers as part of their name. Dead end. I know one city which put a grid on the city core - no street names. Just little things like "A 5".